# Mysql.innodb_table_stats & mysql.innodb_index_stats not updating

Tags: mysql, statistics

I believe I have persitent stats configured correctly and there are records in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS table but the following tables have no data for many of the tables/indexes. mysql.innodb_table_stats & mysql.innodb_index_stats .
Has anyone ever seen this before?
I tried running ANALYZE but still there were no records added.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Variable_name                                          | Value         |
+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                               | ON            |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked                     | OFF           |
| innodb_stats_persistent                                | ON            |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages                   | 20            |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                              | 8             |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages                    | 8             |
+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Any clues here?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html

Comment: MySQL 8.0? Try setting global `information_schema_stats_expiry=0`. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103197

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  It is MySQL 5.7 so no information_schema_stats_expiry.  As far as persistant stats is concerned they look to be configured. I even ran analyze table and still no records in innodb_table_stats or innodb_index_stats.  There are records for some tables.  The table is partitioned.  Does this make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  There is a row in the table for each partion.  I was the filtering on table name not the partition name.